# Error when using FromSql and include ("The Include operation is not supported when calling a stored procedure.")

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

I used Asp.Net Core version 2 and code-first. I tried to use `.FromSql` to call a stored procedure. I did the same as Microsoft said:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
                   .Include(b => b.Posts)
                   .ToList();
```

and my stored procedure only contains the line of code

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCouffierSearch]  
 AS
 BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT * 
     FROM AspNetUsers
END
```

My code in the API:

```
public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> SelectNearByUser()
{
    var query = "execute dbo.GetCouffierSearch";
    var res = _context.Users.FromSql(query);
    return res.Include(x => x.CoiffeurServiceLevels);
}
```

and my class `ApplicationUser` contains definition for `CoiffeurServiceLevels` with type of `ICollection`:

```
public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
        public ApplicationUser()
        {         
            //CoiffeurServiceLevels = new Collection<CoiffeurServiceLevel>();
            //Requests = new Collection<Request>();
            //Tickets = new Collection<Ticket>();        
            //UserRatings = new Collection<Rating>();
            //CouffierRatings = new Collection<Rating>();
        }

        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }

        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public Language Language { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Lng { get; set; }
        public string PersonalId { get; set; }

        public Place Places { get; set; }
        public long? PlaceId { get; set; }

        public int? CouffierNumber { get; set; } = 1;

        public long CityId { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }

        public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
        public string ConfirmedToken { get; set; }
        public string ResetPasswordlToken { get; set; }
        public  DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public bool Gender { get; set; } 

        //#region RelationsClass

        public virtual ICollection<CoiffeurServiceLevel> CoiffeurServiceLevels { get; set; }
        // public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        ////public ICollection<Request> RequestsCouffier { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Rating> UserRatings { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Rating> UserRatingsBy { get; set; }
        //public ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }

        //Roles = new Collection<IdentityUserRole>();
        //#endregion
}
```

When I call it, I get this error:

> Message: The Include operation is not supported when calling a stored procedure.
>   Source: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a significant difference between `$"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})"` and `"execute dbo.GetCouffierSearch"`.

Comment: The error message is crystal clear - what about it do you not understand? If you're calling a stored procedure, you **CANNOT** use `.Include()`.

Comment: Second @marc_s. The error literally tells you what you're trying to do is not possible. `Include` adds a JOIN clause to your query, which is not possible with a stored procedure. Simple as that. If you need to join something, that needs to be part of your stored procedure.

Comment: I Add my stored procedure query as string but i still have same message

Comment: var query = @"
     SELECT AspNetUsers.*
  FROM AspNetUsers 
         join [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] on AspNetUsers.Id=AspNetUserRoles.UserId and  
               AspNetUserRoles.RoleId ='cdd0e1ce-6b57-4b47-827e-7495d11aa16b' 
";
var users= _context.Users.FromSql(query);

Comment: You cannot mix the `FromSql` and `Include`, that's it. No matter how do you do that. You need to call procedure via LinqToSql to be able use the `Include`

Comment: var searchTerm = ".NET";
it should work as microsoft said in their documentation 
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql($"SELECT * FROM dbo.SearchBlogs({searchTerm})")
    .Include(b => b.Posts)
    .ToList();

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: You don't seen that the MS example uses a `SELECT` and your code does not? That probably makes all the difference. Have you tried including a SELECT in your command? If yes, put that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly load a navigation property via the DbContext.Entry(...) API.adfadfa API. You can read more:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit

```
    public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> SelectNearByUser()
    {
        var query = "execute dbo.GetCouffierSearch";
        var res = _context.Users.FromSqlRaw(query).ToList();
         foreach (var item in res)
            {
                _context.Entry(item)
                        .Collection(x => x.CoiffeurServiceLevels)
                        .Load();
             }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure about the code you provided ? I cannot pass collection to Entry() method, so I had to use

`foreach (var user in users) { this.Entry(user).Collection(navigationProperty => navigationProperty.CoiffeurServiceLevels).Load();}`

* in my case I also had to remove `AsNoTracking()` method which was removing the loaded child collections

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and have found that if you load both entities separately they auto-link together as long as the data model supports this.

I have customer entities loaded via a stored procedure with a showroom ID and I wanted to display the name of the showroom from the showroom table:

First I populate the showrooms:

```
Showroom = await _context.Showroom.ToListAsync();
```

Then I call my stored procedure for the customer object:

```
Customer = await _context.Customer
            .FromSql("EXEC sp_GetCustomerList @SearchString, @SortString", searchParam, sortParam)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Lastly I can now access the values from the showrooms list using this syntax:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Showroom.ShowroomName)
```

I am not sure if there is much of a performance impact doing it this way as you are essentially executing two queries rather than one.

Answer (score -2):

I Used Ado.net And Call Procedure

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString))
            {
                string sql = "<ProcedureName>";
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceId", string.Join(',', servicesIds.ToArray()));

                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", page);
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PageSize", pageSize);
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
```