# Why is using a CTE with Include in Entity Framework Core causing this error: "The Include operation is not supported when calling a stored procedure"

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core, common-table-expression

I realise that this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122425/error-when-using-fromsql-and-include-the-include-operation-is-not-supported-wh), however (what I feel is) a key difference is that on the surface my code does not involve a stored procedure.

Essentially I am trying to do this:

```
FormattableString fs = $"My Statment";

var x = _myEntitySet.FromSql(fs)
                .Include(a => a.SubTable)
                .Include(a => a.OtherTable)
                .ToList();
```

What I find is that if my SQL query includes a CTE (common table expression) - even one as simple as this:

```
FormattableString fs = $"WITH CTE AS (SELECT 1 AS [Column1]) SELECT * From MyTable}";
```

I get the following error:

> The Include operation is not supported when calling a stored procedure.

As I am not (knowingly) calling a stored procedure I find the error odd and was wondering why it is happening and if there is some way to work around it so that I can use `Include` with a SQL statement that includes one or more CTEs.

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.0.

Comment: I guess the message is misleading. The exception seems to be thrown for any query string which doesn't start with "select"

Comment: I was wondering that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql states that "SQL statements other than SELECT are recognized automatically as non-composable" but my statement is a select (if one preceded by a CTE).

Comment: Yeah, the question is though what does "other than SELECT" mean. I suspect they check just the first word in the string - after all it's not their job to write SQL parsers.

Comment: Looking more deeply, I think the key is "This means that the SQL passed should not contain any characters or options that are not valid on a subquery" from the link. Basically they need something which is valid if used as "select * from (your_sql)", and CTEs are top level construct which cannot be used inside subquery AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense (although the error message is still misleading). I think I can get around the limitation by creating views instead of CTEs or by defining a table-valued function. Still it would be nice if there was a way which didn't involve creating permanent database objects.